# How to record dektop sound from chrome browser microphone?

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, microphone

I want to record the sound of  a YouTube video with Google Docs "Voice Typing" using Chrome.

It seems that this is possible for Mac/Windows by adding a fake-microfone that takes desktop sounds as input as explained at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erx9czQsY2Q

Is it possible to create such a fake microphone for Ubuntu, so that I can use the "Chrome Browser" microphone to record my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Not a working answer but may depends on pc type :

- With "pulseaudio volume control" (pavucontrol, to beinstalled if not present), you can add , in  input device tab, a "monitor of audio internal" so that playing sound can be recorded by f.i. Audacity  .
  To do so, select "all input devices" in the input device bottom ,then click on the green button on the right of the new "monitor " input, to make it  default.

Unfortunately ,on my pc, it works fine with Audacity but not Chrome+ Google doc voice typing (only internal mic source works) .

- Other way: in Youtube, you can activate subtitle then get subtile text in the "transcription" tab (underneath the video window) and copy/paste in word processor.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The tooltip for the green button on the "Input devices" tab says "Set as fallback" but it actually means "Select as default recording source".